# Rearrange the list in a specific way

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

Suppose I have a list like `{"e", "c", "a", "d", "b"}` and list of rules `{1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 2}`. The second list says that for example element on position 1 shoud be on position 5 and so on. So the desired result is `{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}`. How it can be done in the fastest and elegant way?

Comment: No, the `First /@rules` is the same as `Range[Length[firstList]]`.

Comment: Your suggestion is working thanks a lot. But what do you mean by the direct use?

Answer (score 21):

A bit simpler:

```
Permute[lst, SparseArray[order]]
```

Example:

```
lst = {"e", "c", "a", "d", "b"};
order = {1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 2};
Permute[lst, SparseArray[order]]
```

> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}

Comment: Beautiful! +1 :-)

Comment: Darn it! Forgot about the matrix form for `Permute`. :-(  (+1)

Answer (score 14):

By using assignment to parts. *Update: now cleaner.*

```
fn[list_, r_] :=
  Module[{n = list},
    n[[Values @ r]] = n[[Keys @ r]];
    n
  ]
```

Test:

```
x = {"e", "c", "a", "d", "b"} ;
r = {1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 2};

fn[x, r]
```

> ```
> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
> ```

### Performance

This outperforms even Shadowray's elegant code:

```
x = RandomReal[1, 50000];
r = #2[Thread[# -> #2[#]]] &[Range@50000, RandomSample];

a = Permute[x, SparseArray[r]];   // RepeatedTiming
b = fn[x, r];                     // RepeatedTiming

a === b
```

> ```
> {0.016, Null}
>
> {0.0048, Null}
>
> True
> ```

#### Optimization for a specific format

If all positions are specified and in order as in the example, we can simplify:

```
f2[list_, r_] := Module[{n = list}, n[[Values @ r]] = n; n]
```

This can be very fast:

```
r = Sort[r];

c = f2[x, r]; // RepeatedTiming

a === c
```

> ```
> {0.0010, Null}
>
> True
> ```

---

### Old answer

If the position of every element is specified, as in the example, we can use:

```
x = {"e", "c", "a", "d", "b"} ;
r = {1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 2};

x[[ Ordering @ Values @ Sort @ r ]]
```

> ```
> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
> ```

`Sort` is redundant if the rules are already sorted but I included it for robustness.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming:

```
lst = {"e", "c", "a", "d", "b"};
order = {1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 2};
```

1. `lst[[#]] & /@ First /@ SortBy[order, Last]`
2. `lst[[#]] & /@ Keys[SortBy[order, Last]]`
3. `lst[[Keys[SortBy[order, Last]]]]`

Answer (score 7):

You may use [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html) and [`FindCycles`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCycles.html).

With

```
vals = {"e", "c", "a", "d", "b"};
pos = {1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 2};
```

Then

```
Permute[vals, Cycles@Map[Last, FindCycle[pos, {1, ∞}, All], {2}]]
```

> ```
> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
> ```

`FindCycle` will find more than one cycle if they exists in the rules of `pos` and `Permute` will apply all of them.

Hope this helps.

*Also* `vals[[Ordering[Values@r]]]` but I need to think if this will work with multiple cycles but have to go right now.

Answer (score 5):

A bit less elegant:

```
values = {"e", "c", "a", "d", "b"};
pos = {1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 2};
list = Table[{}, {i, 1, Length[values]}];
Table[list[[pos[[i, 2]]]] = values[[pos[[i, 1]]]], {i,1,Length[values]}];

list
```

gives {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}

Comment: +1 because after a half hour of independent development I realize that ended up with a cleaner version of your assignment.  You might take a look at my answer to see how this might be done in a more concise and efficient way.

Comment: I should definitely consider using the mapping functionality...

Answer (score 5):

```
Thread[SparseArray[rules] -> lst] // SparseArray // Normal
```

or:

```
rules // SparseArray // Normal // SparseArray[# -> lst] & // Normal
```

Previous versions:

```
SparseArray[Thread[ rules[[;; , 2]] -> lst[[rules[[;; , 1]]]]]] // Normal

{lst, rules} // Apply[Thread[Values[#2] -> #[[Keys@#2]]] &] //SparseArray // Normal
```

> {a, b, c, d, e}